# Invoking Nitpick and Sledgehammer together in Isabelle

Tags: theorem-proving, isabelle

When I state a lemma in *Isabelle*, I often type `nitpick`, and if that doesn't give me a counterexample.
I then type `sledgehammer` to try to find a proof automatically.

I wonder: is it possible to invoke *Nitpick* and *Sledgehammer* so that they run concurrently? 
Since *Sledgehammer* is already sending off my lemma to a bunch of automatic provers, couldn't one of those provers actually be a counterexample-finder such as *Nitpick*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using the `try` command in Isabelle; it runs `sledgehammer`, `nitpick`, `quickcheck` and a number of other solvers (such as `auto`, `simp`, `force`, etc) in parallel, giving you the results of the first one that finishes.

For example, running the following:

```
lemma "(a * (b + 1)) = (a * b + a)"
  try
```

will return a counter-example from `nitpick`, indicating that the theorem is not true in general. Adding a type constraint:

```
lemma "((a :: nat) * (b + 1)) = (a * b + a)"
  try
```

will now return a message telling you that `simp` is able to solve the goal.

Finally, changing the type constraint to the more challenging `32 word` type (available from `Word` in `HOL-Word`):

```
lemma "((a :: 32 word) * (b + 1)) = (a * b + a)"
  try
```

will return a result from sledgehammer.

Comment: A more lightweight variant is `try0`, which only tries proof methods, but leaves out the more heavyweight `sledeghammer`, `nitpick`, `quickcheck` calls.